# jquery tablesorter pager is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, tablesorter

Hi i am using jquery table sorter with pager.I am having four tables and pager for each.Displaying table and corresponding pager while clicking the button.while clicking the first and second button,pager for table is working fine.

But while clicking the third and fourth button,i am getting 
the following error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'widgets' of undefined " and pager is not working.

```
Code called in OnLoad:

   $("#tableTest").hide(); // Hide the table in onload
   $("#tableTest").tablesorter(); // Trigger the tablesorter in onload
   $("#tableTest").trigger("update"); // Trigger the update function for table in onload
   $("#tableTest").tablesorterPager({ container: $("#pagerTest") }); // Trigger the pager for table in onload


Code After displaying the table
   $("#tableTest").trigger("update");
   $("#tableTest").data("tablesorter").widgets = ["zebra"];
   $("#tableTest").trigger('applyWidgets');
   $('header,body,html').animate({ scrollTop: $('header').height() }, 4);
```

Please guide me what is the problem and where i am wrong.Pager is not working fine for third and fourth table.

Comment: Can you show the code for all four tablesm and how you are updating them... to me it sounds like a table (and not the contents of the tbody) is being completely replaced, and tablesorter is not being re-initialized - `trigger("update")` only works for tbody updates.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, `$("#tableTest").data("tablesorter")` returns `null`.
Are you sure that tablesorter is storing it's init data in `.data('tablesorter')`? Which tablesorter plugin are you using (there is several)?

Comment: I have used the sample code from this link [link](https://www.novell.com/communities/coolsolutions/jquery-tablesorter-pagination-and-sorting-made-simple/) and i cant able to understand your question about init data

Comment: tablesorter has been storing its `config` variables within `.data('tablesorter')` since at least version 2.0.5 (at tablesorter.com).